# Pressing enter while focused on input causes sibling button to fire

Tags: reactjs, forms, event-bubbling

In a react app, there's a form with some buttons and input as below:

```
<form>
  <div>
    {
      ['1', '10', '100'].map(val => (
        <button onClick={() => console.log(val)}>
          {val}
        </button>
    }
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type='string' /> 
  </div>
</form>
```

When focused on the input field, pressing 'Enter' causes the first button to fire (`console.log('1')`).

It seems related to some default form behaviour, as changing `<form>` element to `<div>`, fixes the issue.

And adding `event.preventDefault()` to the input's `onKeyDown` handler also fixes the issue, which suggests there is some event bubbling involved.

From my understanding, pressing 'Enter' when focused on input field in a form causes form submission, and event bubbling should only trigger parent handlers, so this is quite confusing to me that the first button, which is in a sibling element would be triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right, there is `type` property in the button element - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_type.asp
Also, you can get noticed the default `type` property is `submit`, so it means button could be fired when pressing `enter` key.

I think you can resolve the issue by setting the `type` property to `button` like below.

```
<button type="button" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So the default form submission behaviour is triggering the first available button of type submit and the issue isn't related to event bubbling at all.

Comment: Yup, that's right, glad to hear that you've resolved the issue